# No Power to Thermostats - Even after Replacing

Tags: hvac, thermostat

I changed my thermostats from `Honeywell Smart TH6220wf2006/u Lyric T6 Pro WiFi` to `Honeywell T5 Programmable (NOT Smart)` and couldn't get my furnace to push air out, but AC worked fine.

A friend was over and said I probably blew a fuse and started messing around.  Next thing you know no power at all to the thermostats - no AC or heat.

I called in a pro - they installed a new control panel on the evaporator condensing unit or something.  AC and heat blow - but still no power to thermostats.

I ran to Home Depot and bought new thermostats thinking that somehow the units got fried.  Nope - installed new thermostats - still no power.  Checked the breaker it appears fine.

- None of the thermostats require batteries.
- I have my yellow wire rigged in with the red - so currently the AC is running

Thoughts on what could be wrong?

Comment: You need to provide more information such as make and model of the thermostats and the power needed (24 or 120 vac). Why didn't the electrician address your power problem? Is there a battery in your thermostats? Why did you change the original thermostats? etc.

Comment: Original thermostats were Honeywell Smart TH6220wf2006/u lyric t6 pro wi-fi thermostas.  Replaced with Honeywell  T5 Programmable- programmable (NOT Smart).  Neither have batteries.  I have my yellow wire rigged in with the red - so currently the AC is running.  Just unsure why no power is going to the thermostats.  All relay and switches were also checked while servicing the unit and everything was working. Again just no display power to the thermostats.

Comment: Miswiring a thermostat *can* blow the control board.  Does this involve the C-wire and are you using it correctly? Are you wiring a 2-transformer system with a separate Rh and Rc wire?

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at both the thermostat and the air-handler/furnace?

Comment: I put the details from a comment into the original question so they're more discoverable. Please feel free to [edit] your question to provide answers to any other questions that may be asked of you, like providing pics of the wiring.

Comment: Have you measured the output of the transformer? That would have been my first step.